# Tool-panel transform controls locked to origin

Tags: transforms, origin, tools

‘Must have pushed something’, as grandma says during her daily smartphone meltdowns. I’ll be more patient with her next time!

In edit mode, the move/scale/rotate/etc color arrows are wherever I click on the mesh, but suddenly in object mode they’re locked down on the grid.
Watched a bunch of videos, googled a bunch more, tried some set-origin changes, nothing doing.
If I hadn’t restarted blender to try to solve this, I could have just undone my way back, but blender unlike some apps saves all settings, and undo history is wiped, so I’m here.

Sorry for this noobness, and thank youuuuuuuu!

R

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Sorry, it's not clear what you're asking. What do you mean by the controls are "locked down on the grid"? As you wrote in the title transform controls work on the object's origin. That's normal behavior. You might have applied the Location to the jacket so its origin is now at the world's origin. If you don't like that you can set the object's origin with help of the menu (Object > Set Origin > Origin To Geometry)

Comment: Or you can do your transformations in edit mode (press TAB) and then the gizmo will go back to the geometry

Comment: thank you guys, didn't see the comments, was checking on status and it kept saying 0 answers. coming back from edit didn't help, the color-arrow 'gizmo' was still down at feet at xyz 000. so i did have to select all and set origin to geometry, now when select for example hand, gizmo is on the hand, not at feet. still a mystery how it happened suddenly, never even knew what origin was, so i couldn't have gone thru those steps before to make this change. maybe a kbd shortcut i mashed. anyway, mr. blunder, if you post your comment as answer, i can mark it as solved, so you can get the credit (?)

Comment: select all and set origin to geometry (mr. blunder's advice)